Log user out from keycloak and session on access token expiry
BRIEF PROJECT DESCRIPTION
In my Next.JS 14.2.3 project I'm using NextAuth.JS v4 together with SSO Keycloak OAuth2. Keycloak server is ran not by me, I just have issuer link and all necessary data.

PROBLEM DESCRIPTION
There are 2 sites including mine who use this endpoint and I have an assumption that problem comes from here (I might be mistaken here). I think that when user is logged in on one site, gets his access token, then comes to my site and he already has active access token. This assumption built on cases when I user comes to the site and none of the request gives me 200 as access token is already invalid. At this point I assume lifespan of the token and my session ARE same.

WHAT I ALREADY TRIED
First idea apparently was token rotation. Here I faced a problem which described here. Problem which states that NextAuth.JS does not persist refreshed token which makes it at least very hard to update access token. There are workarounds how to solve it but I prefer just to drop user from the session.
Then I had a thought that if there is a mismatch between token and session lifespan and I can't refresh it then I can just check if token is already expired, and if not then just log user out.

CODE
options.ts:
import { jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode';
import { NextAuthOptions, Session } from 'next-auth';
import { JWT } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import KeycloakProvider from 'next-auth/providers/keycloak';
import { signOut } from 'next-auth/react';
import { keycloakEnvs } from '@/envs';

export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
   session: {
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60,
      updateAge: 12 * 60 * 60,
   },
   secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
   pages: {
      error: '/auth/error',
   },
   providers: [
      KeycloakProvider({
         clientSecret: keycloakEnvs.CLIENT_SECRET ?? '',
         clientId: keycloakEnvs.CLIENT_ID ?? '',
         issuer: keycloakEnvs.ISSUER ?? '',
      }),
   ],
   events: {
      async signOut({ token }: { token: JWT }) {
         const logOutUrl = new URL(
            `${keycloakEnvs.ISSUER}/protocol/openid-connect/logout`,
         );

         if (token.id_token) {
            logOutUrl.searchParams.set('id_token_hint', token.id_token as string);
         } else {
            logOutUrl.searchParams.set('client_id', keycloakEnvs.CLIENT_ID || '');
         }

         logOutUrl.searchParams.set(
            'post_logout_redirect_uri',
            process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL || '',
         );

         await fetch(logOutUrl.toString());
      },
   },
   callbacks: {
      async jwt({ token, account }) {
         if (account) {
            token.access_token = account.access_token;
            token.id_token = account.id_token;
            token.provider = account.provider;

            const { roles = [] } =
               jwtDecode<{ roles: string[] }>(account.access_token || '') || {};

            token.isAdmin = roles.includes('ROLE_ADMIN');
         }

         if (token.exp && +token.exp > Date.now() / 1000) {
            const logOutUrl = new URL(
               `${keycloakEnvs.ISSUER}/protocol/openid-connect/logout`,
            );

            if (token.id_token) {
               logOutUrl.searchParams.set('id_token_hint', token.id_token as string);
            } else {
               logOutUrl.searchParams.set('client_id', keycloakEnvs.CLIENT_ID || '');
            }

            logOutUrl.searchParams.set(
               'post_logout_redirect_uri',
               process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL || '',
            );

            // console.log({ logOutUrl });

            try {
               const response = await fetch(logOutUrl.toString(), {
                  method: 'POST',
                  body: JSON.stringify({ token: token.id_token }),
               });

               console.log({ response });

               if (!response.ok) {
                  console.error('Failed to log out:', response.statusText);
               }

               await signOut();
            } catch (error) {
               console.error('Error during logout:', error);
            }
         }

         return token;
      },
      async session({ session, token }: { session: Session; token: JWT }) {
         if (token) {
            session.user!.access_token = token.access_token as string;
            session.user!.isAdmin = token.isAdmin as boolean;
         } else {
            await signOut();
         }

         return session;
      },
   },
};

For the logout also tried
await fetch(logOutUrl.toString());

and console.log({ response }) tells me
{
  response: Response {
    status: 200,
    statusText: '',
  ...

So I know that request is being executed but nothing happens

EXPECTED BEHAVIOR
If access token already expired it should log user out from current session and from keycloak session
